# How to compare two data series in one bar using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, data-science

I want to compare the number of survivors with gender.
I have something like:

```
Name, Survived, Sex
John, 0, male
Ana, 1, female
Leo, 1, male
Peter, 0, male
```

And trying to create a bar chart which should look like here:
https://pythonspot.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/barchart_python.png.webp

I tried this way

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('titanic_data/train.csv')


figure1 = plt.bar(range(4), data[data['Sex']=='male']['Survived'].value_counts(), label='Male')
figure2 = plt.bar(range(4), data[data['Sex']=='female']['Survived'].value_counts(), label='Female')
plt.legend()
plt.xticks(np.arange(4), rotation=0)
plt.title("Third class survivors")

plt.show()
```

But it says "ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape". What should I do?

Comment: You can do with seaborn [barplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html).

Comment: You can use seaborn countplot with respecful x,y values, and set the hue to be your divosion column http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html#seaborn.countplot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

First: You have **extra whitespace** in your column names while reading the values from your csv file. To get rid of these, you can use `skipinitialspace=True`

Second: You are using `range(4)` for plotting the bars, whereas you have only two bars for both male and female categories. As a result you get `"ValueError: shape mismatch`. Therefore, it is better to use the length of male and female counts

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('titanic_data/train.csv', skipinitialspace=True)

males = data[data['Sex']=='male']['Survived'].value_counts()
females = data[data['Sex']=='female']['Survived'].value_counts()

figure1 = plt.bar(range(len(males)), males, align='edge', width=0.4, label='Male')
figure2 = plt.bar(range(len(females)), females, align='edge', width=-0.4, label='Female')
plt.legend()
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(males)), rotation=0)
plt.title("Third class survivors")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I want the charts to be side by side, not in one bar

Comment: Thank you. But what np.arange(len(males)) means? Why not np.arange(len(females))? I don't understand this line.

Comment: @Eliro : You can also use `np.arange(len(females))` because the length is 2 in both cases. So just choose the value which is larger

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply use the `groupby` method with your example data:

```
Name, Survived, Sex
John, 0, male
Ana, 1, female
Leo, 1, male
Peter, 0, male
```

```py
df.groupby(by=' Sex')[' Survived'].plot.hist()
plt.xticks([0, 1])
plt.legend()
```

which produce:

[image]